# Add Link to img after Onclick Toggle with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I wrote a bit of code (with help from stackoverflow) to toggle two images when clicked. But, I want the second image to be linked to another webpage (eg. The App Store).

How can I add a link to the second image, when the images are always going back and forth when I click them?

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
           $('img',this).attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
        return oldSrc == 'img/button.png' ? 'img/applestoredownload.png' : 'img/button.png';
           });
               $('#slickbox').toggle(400);
           return false;
          });
      });
</script>
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="co-download-app"> 
    <div class="wrapper">
         <div id="imageContainer">
             <a href="#1" id="slick-toggle">
                 <img src="img/button.png"/>
             </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where should I add the link that is only reachable by clicking the second image?

Comment: 3 opening divs but only 1 closing div? your HTML code should be edited.

Comment: Can you provide a http://JSfiddle.net

Comment: I'd advise changing your approach slightly: have both linked images in your HTML, but one of them set to `display:none;` (or to not display via a class). Then on click, toggle their visibility via CSS(-class). This is clearer and more maintainable then magic values somewhere in your JS.

Comment: @robinhuang I wrote you an answer, please check it and tell me it answers to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your question is when you click on a link that contains an image, the image source will be changed and for the next time when you click on the link again it will redirect to the links `href`.

One solution is to change something in your code after first-time clicking on the link to use it later. In this case I gave a class to the link and next time you click on the link it will check to see if it has the class or not. If the `follow-href` class is present it'll skip the rest and if it isn't image source will be changed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('follow-href')) {
            var $img = $(this).find("img");
            var src = ($img.attr('src') == 'img/button.png') ? 'img/applestoredownload.png' : 'img/button.png';
            $img.attr('src', src);
            $(this).addClass('follow-href');
            $('#slickbox').toggle(400);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

*I changed some of your code, but the result should be the same and I hope you don't mind.*

Comment: Okay, I kind of get it. So the first time, the class is not present so it will toggle the image. The second time, the image will have the class so it will stop. Where should I add the link? I only have one <img> in the HTML right now so should I write another?

Comment: @robinhuang Thanks for your reply, I'm sorry if I didn't explain it well enough. You can just put your link in the `href` of `#slick-toggle` link. On the first click, you are using `return false` which prevents the href to work, the second time it should work.

Comment: you genius. that worked perfectly. thank you so much!!